# How to find out where job position is located? (internships)

Tags: internship, location

I have been recently applying to a lot of internships through LinkedIn, GlassDoor, and other websites.

About 50% of the time the positions do not have a location listed and I can infer from the company's size that they most likely have multiple locations.

I am wanting to stay within 4-5 hours of my home which is why I wish to know the location. I also look for a contact email on the post, but none has ever been present.

I have never aggressively job searched on my own (usually with recruiter or job fair representative) and I find it difficult to find this information.

I sent applications to some of the companies even though I have no idea what there location is.

**Where should I be looking or is there a specific area of the company I contact to verify the location? Or is this common?**

*I don't want to waste my time or the company's time.*

Comment: If it isn't posted, and there is no contact person, try contacting the HR department generally.  Just ask them. 

If that doesn't work, apply.  It may be that they have internships available in multiple locations, or maybe in "any" - as in maybe you can pick.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to contact various companies to find out where the job opportunities are, you can do the following:

Add or modify a sentence in the cover letter or the Objective section of the resume resulting in something like this:

> Expand my technical skills through an internship or similar opportunities in the southern Virginia area.

In that example it is clear early on to whomever reads it that if the opportunity is not located in southern Virginia I will likely not be interested in it.  Adjust the area to match where you are interested in.

You can then safely send out your resume to a wide audience with minimum concern that you will waste people's time.  As soon as they read it they will throw your resume out if they have no work in that area.

To answer your second question about if this is common.  The answer is yes, but with some exceptions (like applying for work as a cashier at a store, typically jobs that you don't need resumes to get).